# Will a CDN improve my SEO results?

Tags: seo, cdn

My website is hosted in the US and I was wondering if a CDN will help improve my SEO with search engines.

Comment: Sorry but there is already plenty of related questions and answers regarding [usage of CDN and SEO value](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=CDN+seo+is+question).

Comment: Next time I will do more research before I post questions, thank you for finding questions relating to this